# Definition of (not provided) in the Analytics tool set of a SE site

Tags: support, moderator-tools

What does (not provided) mean in the /admin/analytics Search Keywords table?
Where are those keywords coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an effect of [Google switching logged-in users to encrypted search](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html). The requests of those users no longer contain the keywords that were used for the search.

StackExchange still could access those via the Google Webmaster Tools, as far as I understand it, but the analytics tabs for mods get the data from Google Analytics referrers which don't provide this information anymore for a portion of Google users.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the keywords were what the user entered in a search engine which lead to the particular post.